# Rxjs Subscription triggers more than once

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

It's very mysterious my subscription is getting triggered more than once - I don't know what was my mistake - I followed the same method on another but it doesn't get triggered more than once

```
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  constructor() {
    this.getpatientId = this.bindPatientId.asObservable();
  }

  bindPatientId: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
  getpatientId: Observable<number>;

  setPatientId(patientId: number) {
    this.bindPatientId.next(patientId);
  }

  bindTabId: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
}
```

Setting new value to the `Subject`

```
 toggleProfile(patientId: number) {
    this.commonService.setPatientId(patientId);
    this.route.navigate(['/endrolPatient']);
  }
```

Listening from another component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._common.getpatientId.subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.patientID = res;
        console.log("console inside observable", this.patientID);
      });
}
```

In my console when I pass `123` - I'm getting `console inside observable 123` but after the first observer rest all the subscriptions get doubled and logging twice in my console - Please help me to fix it

Comment: What do you mean by `after the first observer rest`? Please also give some insight (code) into how your components (that subscribe to the observable from the service) are created

Comment: If i add new value to the `subject` the observers are getting triggered with value multiple times but for the first change it triggers only once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is probably because your component is getting destroyed and created again. So when your component destroys, you have to destroy all the subscriptions. You can do this in `ngOnDestroy` life cycle method

code:

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

private sub: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._common.getpatientId.subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.patientID = res;
        console.log("console inside observable", this.patientID);
      });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
   this.sub.unsubscribe():
}
```

Comment: No it get's unsubscribed and it's not even triggering any value - after your solution

Comment: After my solution its not triggering any value? What does that mean? I have only explained how to kill the subscriptions, when not in use and avoiding multiple subscriptions for every visit to the component. That has nothing to do in stopping the value being triggered.

Comment: Yeah but what i experienced is that none of the observers receive any data

Comment: Well, that is the issue then. Did you try `ReplaySubject(1)` or `BehaviorSubject`? They both should work. Because you are subscribing to an observable that has already emitted a value.

Comment: I tried `BehaviourSubject` i will try `ReplaySubject()` and let you know

Comment: No - Nothing is working - same result for both cases - i get values multiple times

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo reproducing your issue?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvc61h?embed=1&file=src/app/common.service.ts)

Comment: `Patients` component is not at all activated and there is no route to activate it in your code. So subscription is not yet done. Can you update your example?

Comment: I still do not understand what is the issue. I changed it to BehaviorSubject in your code and it is working fine. Note that your emitting in loop, but subscription is happening after that, so you will get only the last value, If you use `ReplaySubject(10)`, then you would get last 10 values. Check this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4ns74?file=src/app/common.service.ts

Comment: In my original code i din't use any looping to set the value - but it's working good on your example - in my case it triggers more than once - I'm unable to replicate this issue on stackblitz - anyway thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Use Behaviour Subject whenever you use Subject for everything !, i too faced the problem some time ago but that worked for me !

```
 bindPatientId: Subject<number> = new BehaviourSubject<number>();
 bindTabId: Subject<number> = new BehaviourSubject<number>();
```

Upon subscription, it returns the last value of the subject. A regular observable only triggers when it receives an onnext
and you can also use

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and then add

```
.pipe(
  take(1)
```

before the subscrbe

Have a look here
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html

Hope this may help you !

Comment: No if it's `BehaviourSubject` i need to initialize with a default value for it - I don't want to do that and more over the result is same if I do so - Yeah we can use `take` operator but i want to know why it's getting triggered more than once

Comment: well i think cause you are not destroying it and you are subscribing it without unsubcribing .If this is it u can add ngOndestroy method and unsubcribe there